# アクセス数を稼ぐ目的で質問を更新することについて

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, 編集

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/21058/revisions

これは私が１ヶ月くらい前に投稿した質問で
タイトルがわかりにくかったので質問のタイトルを修正して気がついたのですが
質問のタイトルを更新するだけで「アクティブ」という一覧に質問が表示されなおす仕様のようです

私は気づいたのですが、これはアクセス数を稼ぐ目的で故意に「アクティブ」という一覧に表示し直すこともでき、サイトでポイント数を稼ぐ手段としても利用できますよね

もし、売名目的で故意に質問のタイトルなどを若干だけ変更して「アクティブ」な質問として上位をキープしようとするユーザーが現れた場合はどのような対処がされるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 16, accepted):

StackOverflowはコミュニティによる自治が行えるように設計されています。

投稿者の目的が「アクセス数を稼ぐ」なのかどうかを第三者が判断することは不可能ですが、一方でそのように感じる人が多ければ、そのような行為を防ぐ方策がいくつか用意されています。

まずはその質問に対するマイナス投票を行うことができます。
マイナス票が多くなって一定の閾値を超えると質問の一覧に表示されなくなります。

- [信用度とは何ですか？どうしたら上がりますか？また失うのはどんな時ですか？ - ヘルプ センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

質問の内容に問題があるなら[質問のクローズに投票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)することができますし、質問の体裁だけは整えられているというのであれば、モデレータへの通報も可能です。

- [誰かが何か悪いことをしているのを見つけたら? - ヘルプ センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

[モデレータの権限は強力](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)で、質問の保護・ロック・削除などが行えます。

その投稿者が何度も似たような行為を繰り返しているなら、システムからの制限という形で、質問の投稿自体が不可能になります。

- [私のアカウントからの質問が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか? - ヘルプ センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

投稿者が捨てアカウントを何度も取得してそのような行為に及ぶようなら、今度は同一ネットワークからの質問が制限されるようになります。

- [投稿が「お使いのネットワークから多量のスパムおよび不正使用」によりブロックされたのはなぜですか? - ヘルプ センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/abuse-block)